# Is it possible in Pytest to use parameters depending on command line arguments?

Tags: python, pytest

I have some old tests that work like this:

```
test1(some_param):
    ...

test2(some_param):
    ...

call_tests(param):
    for test in all_test:
        test(param)

if arg_a:
    call_tests("foo")
if arg_b:
    call_tests("bar")
```

I'd like to convert them to use Pytest and do so the correct way. I'd like to do something like this in `conftest.py`

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session",
                params=["foo", "bar"])
def some_param(request):
    return request.param
```

but I haven't found any examples where the params list can be controlled from command line arguments. I'm sure I can hack my way around this, but I was hoping Pytest already has some nice way of doing this. Is that the case, or should I figure out my own way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can pass command line args.
In your conftest.py you can use parser.addoption.  For example:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser", action="store", default="chrome")

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    option_value = meta.config.option.browser
    if 'browser' in metafunc.fixturenames and option_value is not None:
        metafunc.parametrize("browser", [option_value])
```

There is more info [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html)